# Extjs 4.2 - change css for in-active tab

Tags: tabs, extjs4.2

In Extjs 4.2, all the tabs "font-weight" are by default "bold".

I want to change like this

```
.x-tab-default .x-tab-inner {
   font-weight: bold;
 } 
 .x-tab{
   font-weight: normal;
 }
```

But font weight is always bold

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Q7f5q/105/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/Tv4mv/2/

I think that maybe this can helo id you give a

cls : 'tabpanel' and redefined the .x-tab-inner property.

```
cls : 'tabpanel'
```

Comment: In this jsfiddle, active tab font-weight is showing normal but it should be bold